# Integrating $\prod_{i=k+1}^{kN} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_i\right)\times$ with conditions on $p_i$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to integrate this expression which came up in a derivation of the momentum distribution function for an ideal gas. $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function which is $1$ when $x$ is positive and $0$ if negative.

> $$\prod_{i=k+1}^{kN} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_i\right)\times\left[ \Theta\left(2mE - \sum_{i=1}^{kN}p_i^2\right) - \Theta\left(2m(E-\triangle E) - \sum_{i=1}^{kN}p_i^2\right)\right]$$

The integrals here are nested like $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp_{k+1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp_{k+2}\cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty dp_{kN}$

I also want to get some physical intuition as to what this integral means. I have done the integration where the $i$ in the integral goes from $1$ to $kN$. This is easily interpreted as the volume contained in between two $kN$ dimensional spheres of radii $\sqrt{2mE}$ and $\sqrt{2m(E-\triangle E)}$. But in this case what does it mean when $i$ runs from $k+1$ to $kN$?

**EDIT**: There is a condition which I forgot to mention: $$p_1^2+p_2^2+\cdots+p_k^2=constant=a^2 $$
 (To physicists, this means I am fixing the magnitude of momentum of one particle out of $N$ particles in a $k$-dimensional space)

Comment: This needs more context. Conditions on $p_i$ are mentioned in the title, but there is no description of what the $p_i$ are, much less what the conditions on them are. If $m$ is a mass and $E$ an energy then $\sqrt{2mE}$ has the units of a momentum, but it is used as a radius of a sphere.

Comment: @robjohn I want to give this as a purely mathematical problem. You don't need physics (momentum etc) for solving this integral, do you?

Comment: Without any other information $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}p_i$ is meaningless. I am just trying to gather any information at all where there is none given.

Comment: The question is simply this: Do this integration   $\prod_{i=k+1}^{kN} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_i\right)$ subject to $a<\sum_ix_i^2<b$

Comment: @robjohn I have edited the question. I think this condition was needed.

Comment: The problem is that just taken as it is written, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{d}x_i=\infty$. If the $x_i$ are bound in a spherical shell, then if the integrals were nested, your formula might be interpreted as the volume of the shell, but written as a product of disjoint integrals, it is hard to interpret what is meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral can be rewritten as:

> $$\prod_{i=k+1}^{kN} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_i\right)\times\left[ \Theta\left(2mE - a^2 - \sum_{i=k+1}^{kN}p_i^2\right) - \Theta\left(2m(E-\triangle E)-a^2 - \sum_{i=k+1}^{kN}p_i^2\right)\right]$$

Now this is simpy the volume contained between two $kN-k$ dimensional spheres. Since the volume of an $n$ dimensional sphere is $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}R^n$ where $R$ is the radius, the resulting integral simplifies to:

$$\frac{ \pi^{ \frac{kN-k}{2} } }{ \Gamma(\frac{kN-k}{2}+1) }\times \left[ (2mE-a^2)^{\frac{kN-k}{2}}-(2m(E-\triangle E)-a^2)^{\frac{kN-k}{2}} \right]$$

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the question, the notation is not right. The integrals need to be nested. The product of disjoint integrals in each variable is something else, and it is hard to interpret what is meant.

Comment: @robjohn I think you are correct. But in the set of lecture notes that I have the integrals are not nested

Comment: Okay so @robjohn I found out that they are actually nested. Thanks